# How to extract slides created inside Slide Master and use individually on a different PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I did not realize that I was working inside the Slide Master on PowerPoint until I tried to print them all!

Only the first one prints so I closed the slide master and the other slides disappeared! I have been working on this for a couple of hours!!

Is there a way to copy or extract or disable the Slide Master so I can keep and print the slides I already created inside Slide Master?

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried:  a) creating a new slide in normal view then applying the layout corresponding to the slide you created in Master view, or b) for each "slide" in the Master view, select all/copy, switch back to normal view, add a new blank slide and paste.  Neither will leave you with a properly formatted presentation, but one or the other should give you printable slides.

Comment: Yes, I tried that before asking for help :(  It does not work.  I am now thinking that I will try to copy each text box to a new slide and see if that works.  Will get back to you on this as I just thought about it this afternoon, out of the blue.  Thank you for trying to help me, Steve Rindsberg, arke

Comment: I did not understand what your answer is Giacomo 1968!  If you just corrected my writing, that did not help me with the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know that the only way I was able to get my formatting copied to a regular slide show from the master slides was to copy and paste each text box to a new slide show where the master view is not open.
It did take some time but at least I did not have to start from scratch.
Thank you for trying to help me.  I really appreciate it even if my question was a bit unclear maybe or my mistake was one of a kind :)
Stay safe!
Technologically-challenged happy now ;)